# For loops, with replacement in R

Tags: r, loops, replace

I have a dataframe with factors.

```
dat <- c("low", "high", "middle", "middle", "low", "low")
dat <- factor(dat, levels = c("low", "middle", "high")
lvl <- unique(sort(dat))
x <- seq(1,3,1)
```

I want to iterate through each factor and replace the factors with numeric variables if it equals the ith level.

```
for(i in 1:3){
 if(dat == lvl[i]) {
    dat <- x[i]
    }
  }
```

I keep getting this error: `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`.

There must be a simple solution?
EDIT for clarity:

I'm not trying to replace the vector with its corresponding level. I'm trying to replace the entry with the term in some sequence (1,2,3 in this case) that corresponds to the level.

Comment: No time for full answer, but you need to look at `ifelse`, not just `if`.

Comment: How would your desired output will look like?

Comment: So my actual dataset has a character vector of time periods (1850-1854, 1855-1889,1890-1894,...) that lists when a study was done. They are all in 5 year periods. I can't change the characters to numerics but I want to plot the frequency of studies done over time. So I'm trying to replace each period with the term in `seq(1852.5, 2007.5, 5)` that corresponds to the level of the period. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ifelse but for this particular task you can just use as.numeric.

```
dat <- as.numeric(dat)
```

Comment: how would the ifelse statement differ? My actual example I need to replace with a different sequence.

Comment: Can you explain why you didn't ask the question you wanted answered?

Comment: My actual example is based on a large dataset of life tables from the `LifeTables` package. The concept is the exact same, but the only difference is my sequence is `seq(1752.5,2007.5,5)`.

Comment: Use the 'dat'-item I constructed to index a variable name assigned that sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
dat <- factor(c("low", "high", "middle", "middle", "low", "low"))
levels(dat) 
# [1] "high"   "low"    "middle"

lvl = c(99, 86, 123) # New names for level
levels(dat) = lvl
dat
# 86  99  123 123 86  86 
# Levels: 99 86 123
```

Comment: I'm not trying to replace it with the level, I'm trying to replace it with a sequence where each term in the sequence corresponds to the same term in the level eg. `"high"` has a level of 3. So I want to replace it with the third term of my sequence.